# Squiggle using CSS

Tags: css

I am building the basic [Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(game)) card patterns. I can do colours, numbers and fillings, and I have the diamond and oval shapes. Please see my progress in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQQMz/5/).

The last piece of the puzzle is to build a `squiggle` class for the "squiggle" shape. How can I do the squiggle shape using CSS?

[image]

Comment: were you able to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to resort to SVG for shapes like that.

SVG might also make your life easier for those other shapes too. On my Safari 6.0.2 I see a few small CSS rendering artifacts:

In particular, the spacing of the striped diamond due to how `transform` works (texture mapping) produces something that doesn't quite look completely uniform. You'll need to scale up this screenshot to see the artifacts at the corners of the diamond.

[image]

Basically, CSS is not meant for drawing shapes. SVG is meant for drawing shapes. Therefore since you are trying to draw shapes, there's a much higher chance you'll succeed with SVG.

Good job with the diamonds, though. (Note also SVG ought to work on platforms not supporting CSS3 3D; it is a neat trick to skew/scale square to make a diamond but at the end of the day its more or less a hack)

Comment: I guess I could also use images.

Comment: @Randomblue too easy, too big :-)

Comment: @Randomblue That's true too, and gives you even more control. But for simple shapes like these Set shapes SVG is pretty much perfect...